# EXCEL FORMULA HELP TO FILTER DATA

Tags: excel

I have the below list of 2 columns in excel.I need to omit those CSI Id's for which atleast even 1 RRP ID row is non blank.We can add extra column to flag and then filter it based on the flag.

Basically last 2 rows with CSI ID 8 and 9 should show a flag 0 and rest all as 1.

[image]

Comment: are you allowed to use VBA/macro?

Comment: No Macros are not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would just be a COUNTIFS i.e.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>")
```

in column C would give a count >0 for all rows except the last two and you can filter on it.